# Could not find Cypress test run results

Tags: vue.js, cypress, github-actions

I created a new Vue project via `npm init vue@latest` and selected Cypress.

Currently there are no tests yet, I have a placeholder test `/cypress/e2e/example.cy.ts` with

```
describe("My First Test", () => {
  it("visits the app root url", () => {
    cy.visit("/");
  });
});
```

I'm using Cypress v11.0.1 and have a script to run the cypress tests inside my Github Actions

```
"test:e2e:ci": "start-server-and-test preview :4173 'cypress run --e2e'",
```

This is my Cypress action

```
  - name: Check if e2e tests are passing
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
    with:
      build: npm run build
      start: npm run test:e2e:ci
```

Sometimes **( it occurs very rarely )** the Github workflow fails with

[image]

As you can see the test itself passes. I can fix the pipeline by running it again...

Does someone know why this happens and how to avoid this error?

Please let me know if you need more information ( e.g. configuration files )